# How to Sort Form Input Automatically With React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, forms, asynchronous, react-hooks

I have a form where user can enter a name that will then be displayed on a list. Upon entering a new name the list should automatically be sorted in alphabetical order. Current attempt with `useEffect` does work but is buggy(list will only be sorted after user start deleting previous input text).

A few notable things to highlight with current setup:

- **Submission** component is used for rendering list of names
- **Form** component is used to store state of app and input fields
- **handleSortName()** will execute sorting
- **useEffect()** executes **handleSortName()** when there is a change to **submissions** value

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Submission = ({ submission }) => {
  return <div>name: {submission.name}</div>;
};

const Form = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: ""
  });

  const [submissions, setSubmission] = useState([                                        
    { name: "John" }
  ]);

  const addSubmission = (values) => {
    const newSubmissions = [...submissions, values];
    setSubmission(newSubmissions);
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setValues({ ...values, [event.target.name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addSubmission(values);
    handleSortName(submissions);
  };

  const handleSortName = (submissions) => {
    return submissions.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleSortName(submissions);
  }, [submissions]);

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h1>Student Enrollment</h1>
        <div>
          <label>name: </label>
          <input
            required
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={values.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
      </form>
      <h1>Submitted Student</h1>
      {submissions.map((submission, index) => (
        <Submission key={index} submission={submission} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

**Working Sample:** https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-form-oj61v9?file=/src/Form.js

I am aware that `useState` is asynchronous and will not update value right away.
Any suggestion on other implementations such as [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), a custom hook or current UseEffect approach? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATE:***
because `React` re-renders the component when the `props` or `state` changes.
 that means inside your `handleSortName()` function you have to call `setSubmissions` with the **new** sorted array, then `React` will know that the `state` was changed.

```
const handleSortName = (submissions) => {
    // create a new copy of the array with the three dots operator:
    let copyOfSubmissions = [...submissions];
    // set the state to the new sorted array:
    setSubmissions(
      copyOfSubmissions.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
    );
  };
```

or you can do both steps in 1 line:

```
const handleSortName = (submissions) => {
    // set the state to the newly created sorted array with the three dots operator:
    setSubmissions(
      [...submissions].sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
    );
  };
```

[sandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-form-omar-dieh-97swxk)

Comment: I see. With your suggestion `useEffect` can be removed and `handleSortName` is executed in component's return statement. Would you know why this worked instead of executing `handleSortName` inside `handleSubmit`?

Comment: hey @simonxcode the answer was updated :) hope it helps you understanding why it wasn't working.

Comment: also your `const [submissions, setSubmission]` should look like `const [submissions, setSubmissions]` so you don't mix names up for future in you create another state with `const [submission, setSubmission]` :)

Comment: thanks for the update with explanation and alternative with `useEffect`, although it may be "too much" for this simple operation.